# Cant set text in progress bar at the right conor

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this progress and like the text with 0% I also want a text with 100% at the end of the progress bar thats always visible.

```js
function moveProgressBar() {
  var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
  var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
  var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
  var animationLength = 1500;
  // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
  $('.progress-bar').animate({
    left: progressTotal
  }, animationLength);
}

moveProgressBar();
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 500px;
  height:40px;
}

.progress-wrap {
  background: #f80;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar {
  background: #ddd;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 progressbar">
  <div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="20">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 5px;">0%</p><div class="progress-bar progress">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 5px;">110%</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the 100% to stand at the right side and be visible at all time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this way. Remove the `<p>` out of the `<div>`

**Snippet**

```js
function moveProgressBar() {
  var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
  var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
  var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
  var animationLength = 1500;
  // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
  $('.progress-bar').animate({
    left: progressTotal
  }, animationLength);
}

moveProgressBar();
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 500px;
  height:40px;
}

.progress-wrap {
  background: #f80;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar {
  background: #ddd;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 progressbar">
  <div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="20">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 5px;">0%</p>
    <div class="progress-bar progress">
    </div>
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 5px;">110%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it for 0, do same for 100%.

```js
function moveProgressBar() {
  var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
  var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
  var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
  var animationLength = 1500;
  // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
  $('.progress-bar').animate({
    left: progressTotal
  }, animationLength);
}

moveProgressBar();
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
}
.progress-wrap {
  background: #f80;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-bar {
  background: #ddd;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 progressbar">
  <div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="20">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 5px;">0%</p>
    <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 5px;">110%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```